# Lista vacia despues de haberla llenado javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, lista

Hola tengo la siguiente funcion en Javascript que se ejecuta cuando el documento carga, estoy tratando de llenar el array `lista` pero cada vez que lo quiero mostrar con un console.log o un alert (excepto el console.log dentro del foreach, ahi si me muestra datos) me lo muestra vacio, cual es mi error?

```
$(".content-wrapper").ready(function() {

    var vias;
    var lista = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "views/ajax/OIT.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log("cargo");
            if (respuesta == 0) {
                console.log("malo");

            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(respuesta));
                vias = respuesta[0];
                console.log("Primer console", vias.tipo);
                vias.forEach(function(valor, indice, array) {
                    console.log(
                        "En el índice " + indice +
                        " hay este valor (propiedad 'tipo'): " + valor.tipo +
                        " (desde ['tipo']): " + valor['tipo'] +
                        " (desde [0]): " + valor[0]
                    );
                    lista[indice] = valor.tipo;
                    console.log("Lista", lista[indice]);

                });

            }
        }


    });
    alert(lista);  //No muestra nada

    console.log("Lista", lista[0]); //Aqui tampoco



});
```

**Salida JSON**

```
[[{"0":"AEREO","tipo":"AEREO"},{"0":"DIRECTO","tipo":"DIRECTO"},{"0":"AEREO","tipo":"AEREO"},{"0":"DIRECTO","tipo":"DIRECTO"},{"0":"MARITIMO","tipo":"MARITIMO"},{"0":"OTROS","tipo":"OTROS"},{"0":"TERRESTRE","tipo":"TERRESTRE"}]]
```

**Salida en consola**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siento que el problema no es JSON porque lo estoy iterando y cuando lo itera inserto lo que necesito "AEREO, MARITIMO, ETC" en la lista usando `lista[indice] = valor.tipo;` por eso despues de la iteración muestra que trae la "lista" en x posición, el problema es que cuando salgo del foreach la lista esta vacia o no muestra nada.

Comment: ¿Qué muestraría un `console.log(respuesta);`
 puesto **inmediatamente**  después del `success`? ¿Cómo retornas los datos desde `OIT.php`?

Comment: creo que no esa convirtiendo el json ¿que muestra en el success?

Comment: `[[{"0":"AEREO","tipo":"AEREO"},{"0":"DIRECTO","tipo":"DIRECTO"},{"0":"AEREO","tipo":"AEREO"},{"0":"DIRECTO","tipo":"DIRECTO"},{"0":"MARITIMO","tipo":"MARITIMO"},{"0":"OTROS","tipo":"OTROS"},{"0":"TERRESTRE","tipo":"TERRESTRE"}]]`

Comment: Prueba con lista.push(valor.tipo);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las llamadas AJAX son asincronicas, el alert y el log del final no muestran nada porque cuando esos se efectuan la respuesta del request ajax(que es la que llena la lista) todavia no llego. 
Si queres que muestren algo deberias colocarlos al final de la funcion success, no hay problema ni en la manera en la que lo mostras ni en la manera en la que agregas los elementos.

Comment: Coloque  `async: false,`y ya funciona, gracias.